# React/NPM: How to encapsulate a component?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have the following working react app that displays a spinning cube.

```
npm create-react-app
```

```
vi src/App.js
```

Copy-paste the content below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

```
npm run build
```

And voila, spinning cube!

---

But, the **very next** thing I try to do is: encapsulate the spinning cube and create some drop-down that allows me to view a cube or something else.

I didn't get as far as a drop-down though, because I could not encapsulate the Cube class beneath a function:

```
mport React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
class ICube extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}
export default function App() {
  var cube = ICube()
  return ( 
      <div ref={ref => (cube.mount = ref)} />
  )   
}
```

This builds, but does not render.  I am not sure how this encapsulation is supposed to proceed.  Is there some particular way to encapsulate this?

I have also tried creating a:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  cube = ICube()
  componentDidMount() {
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.cube.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}
```

As a direct encapsulation, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create refs for this purpose. Simply import your component and use it in your render function

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
class ICube extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className"some-style-class">
         <App />
         {//some other components}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

To render your shape conditionally, you can pass props to your App component like

```js
<App
  shape={this.state.shape} 
/>
```

The value for the type of shape can come from the drop down component you make

Comment: this is what I started with.  If you try to do this, it will not actually work. So, I created the ref.  I am working from this website. https://blog.bitsrc.io/starting-with-react-16-and-three-js-in-5-minutes-3079b8829817

Comment: ok, I saw your edit... It sounds like I may  be very close, but that there are a few things going on that I don't understand.

Comment: what would the App component look like, in this case?

Comment: I've made a working sample for you here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-threejs-forked-31gog?file=/src/CubeScene.js). Purpose of this is to demonstrate how you can have one root component and then have children inside it. Currently, it renders both the shapes, but you can make it conditional. I hope you get the idea behind it

Comment: That is awesome

Comment: I get it now -- this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wanted to make `ICube` render within another component. Simply do

```js
// class component
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ICube />
        {/* more components */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// functional components
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ICube />
      {/* more components */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's not a usual pattern for React to do `cube = ICube()` when using class components. See [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). And composition can be done using a mixture of class components and functional components any way you like.

Comment: Class component version worked.  I assume I would need to modify my `index.js` in order to get the functional version to work?